# How can I regain access to a Google Developer account without TFA?

Tags: google-developer-tools

My organization has a Google Developer account that is tied to an employee who has since resigned. We have the credentials for said account, but we're unable to fully authenticate due to the MFA being tied to his mobile number, which we do not have access to.

I've created a new Google Developer account, but I'm not able to assign it to our organization because of conflicts with the old account.

Any suggestions on how to assign the new account to our organization so I can pay the developer fee and start utilizing the functions?

Thank you!

Comment: Howdy. This isn't the forum for such a question. Maybe try https://superuser.com or a Google-specific site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Google Cloud support directed me here, go figure.